# How do I copy files/folders over to locked folders?

Tags: folder

Sorry for the really dumb question. I've been using elementary for a day now and am trying to copy over the [folder for an extension](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4i8kib/the_faviconreloader_addon_is_gone_if_you_really/) to the Firefox extensions folder (which I finally found). Unfortunately, when I try to do so it tells me that there is an "Eror while copying," and that "The folder "FavIconReloader@mozilla.org" cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination." Being the only user on the OS I'm the Admin, yet can't figure out how to be allowed to copy files over to folders with that little lock on their bottom right corner. I've yet to learn my way around Terminal commands, so I'm wondering if there's a simple GUI option for this that I'm not noticing. Again, sorry for the really basic question.

Comment: I have added an answer.Remember to mark as answer if it works

Comment: @SuiciDoga Ahhhhh, thanks for that, and for answering such a basic question. And yes, I accepted your answer, but I unfortunately can't upvote it as well as I don't have the required reputation points yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running files as an administrator (root) by right clicking **Files** and clicking **Open Files As Administrator**

[image: Menu]

It should be opened as administrator now.

Comment: Mine doesnt show a run as administrator

Comment: It's not working.